# Mobile toolbar/menu hides full website height

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, responsive-design

I found this issue that doesn't seem to have a clear solution to responsively resize in the case of a mobile user accessing a site and the full height stretches over the toolbar/menu unless they manually hide the toolbar.

How can I resize the site so that the height is responsive within the inner height of the window of a mobile device and will auto resize when they hide the toolbar? Here is my test code and a few examples of the problem:

```
import React from "react"
import { styled } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <List>
        <Block />
      </List>
    </>
  );
}

const Block = styled('div')({
  height: 100,
  width: '100%',
  background: 'white',
  marginTop: 'auto',
})

const List = styled('div')({
  display: 'flex',
  height: '100vh',
})

export default App;
```

[image: Test App]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile safari has some interesting interactions with `100vh`. Right now, it bases it off of the collapsed address bar and bottom browser buttons. When those items come back, it still keeps the size at the "scrolled" viewport.

There is a new set of height declarations that help to solve this issue. They are also updating the spec to handle this in the future, but for now this should do the trick:

```js
const List = styled('div')({
    display: 'flex',
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-height: -webkit-fill-available;
})
```

Comment: Thanks got it working, but needed to apply a `height: 100%;` along with this.